# Can't connect to a database using MAMP

Tags: php, pdo, mamp

I am trying to connect to a database with the name `auth` using PHP. I made the database with SequelPro and I am connecting using MAMP My PHP code is

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'auth';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database; $username, $password");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed ". $e->getMessage());
```

Comment: You have written new as nee in try block .pl. check. $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=   $server;dbname=$database;,     $username, $password");

Comment: `host=   $server` there shouldn't be any spaces in there and there's a stray comma in here `;,     $username`. Do spend the time to read the manual over carefully http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: I am on mobile so that was a typo in my question I edited it.

Comment: check for errors then http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @chris85 my mistake. However, OP did have a space in there `host= $server`.

Comment: @chris85 that worked!!

Comment: @chris85 ah, the misplaced quote. Well, the manual's link I left them has the right syntax, as did you.

Answer (score 0):

Your quote usage for the connection is incorrect and makes it so only 1 parameter is being sent to the PDO connection. Correct code:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
```

Simple demo (https://eval.in/647408):

```
function simple($a, $b = 'empty', $c = 'empty') {
     var_dump('a=' . $a);
     var_dump('b=' . $b);
     var_dump('c=' . $c);
}
simple('a,b,c');
echo "\n" . 'version 2' . "\n\n";
simple('a','b','c');
```

Output:

```
string(7) "a=a,b,c"
string(7) "b=empty"
string(7) "c=empty"

version 2

string(3) "a=a"
string(3) "b=b"
string(3) "c=c"
```

With the commas in quotes they aren't read as parameter delimiters.